# What is the use of @ValueSource(classes= .....)

Tags: junit5

In the User Guide for JUnit5  it is mentioned that one of the types that can be used for [`@ValueSource`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-ValueSource) is `java.lang.Class`.

What is the use case for this feature? How can I use it?

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(classes = {/*What goes here?*/})

void test(/*What goes here?*/) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about class literals. `@ValueSource` allows us to specify literal values of different types, and Java supports literal values to refer to references to the instances of class `Class<?>`. So, these would end up being the input to whatever parameterized unit test we are writing. For example:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(classes = { String.class, Integer.class })
void testWithValueSource(Class<?> argument) {
    assertEquals( "java.lang", argument.getPackage().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
@ValueSource(classes = {NoResultException.class, EmptyResultDataAccessException.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(classes = {NoResultException.class, EmptyResultDataAccessException.class})
  public void testOrderNotFound(Class<? extends Exception> clazz) throws Exception {
    when(orderDao.getOrder(ORDER_ID)).thenThrow(clazz);
    assertThrows(OrderNotFoundException.class,
        () -> provisionService.addNumbers(ORDER_ID, USER));
}
```